# How to parse JSON Array to update record in postgreSQL

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I have a Table name called employee_Details with Columns

```
 EMP_ID   NAME  VECH_NO  SALARY
   1       A      1234    100
   2       B      12345   200
```

I Construct JSON array using Java. with structure

> {["EMP_ID":1,"NAME":Y,"VECH_NO":4587,"SALARY":1500],["EMP_ID":3,"NAME":Z,"VECH_NO":4007,"SALARY":1800]}

I need to update full record where EMP_ID exists on table else insert as new record. There is any in build function available in postgreSQL to achieve this. I refer this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html but didn't get solution

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a JSON array. I have to Update if exists else insert it by using any inbuild functions like "json_populate_recordset".

Comment: Seems that you swapped `[]` and `{}` in your example. And what version of PostgreSQL are you using? If before 9.5, can you upgrade (to use new upsert capabilities)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is malformed, I guess the intended was:

```
[
    {"EMP_ID":1,"NAME":"Y","VECH_NO":4587,"SALARY":1500},
    {"EMP_ID":3,"NAME":"Z","VECH_NO":4007,"SALARY":1800}
]
```

Assuming the following table definition:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE employee_details(
    "EMP_ID" integer primary key,
    "NAME" text,
    "VECH_NO" integer,
    "SALARY" numeric
);
```

And a sample data (just to show the update):

```
INSERT INTO employee_details VALUES(1, 'X', 123, 123);
```

You can first use [`json_array_elements` to make each array one row and `json_populate_record` to get each value as the original table type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM
    json_array_elements('[{"EMP_ID":1,"NAME":"Y","VECH_NO":4587,"SALARY":1500},{"EMP_ID":3,"NAME":"Z","VECH_NO":4007,"SALARY":1800}]') AS a(element),
    json_populate_record(NULL::employee_details, a.element) AS r;
```

With that, you can simple use [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

```
INSERT INTO employee_details("EMP_ID", "NAME", "VECH_NO", "SALARY")
(
    SELECT r."EMP_ID", r."NAME", r."VECH_NO", r."SALARY"
    FROM
        json_array_elements('[{"EMP_ID":1,"NAME":"Y","VECH_NO":4587,"SALARY":1500},{"EMP_ID":3,"NAME":"Z","VECH_NO":4007,"SALARY":1800}]') AS a(element),
        json_populate_record(NULL::employee_details, a.element) AS r
)
ON CONFLICT ("EMP_ID") DO
UPDATE SET
    "NAME" = EXCLUDED."NAME",
    "VECH_NO" = EXCLUDED."VECH_NO",
    "SALARY" = EXCLUDED."SALARY"
;
```

The `ON CONFLICT` clause only works on version 9.5 or higher. Before that you have to use [some tricks with loop and retry](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) or writable common table expression (although that has race-condition issues); in any case it is a good reason to upgrade if you are on older versions.

Comment: By using loop I have done Update and insertion. Thank you.